# Matrix logarithm for d-dimensional cyclic permutation matrix

Tags: gr.group-theory, matrix-equations, cycles, matrix-exponential

I want to find the matrix $\hat{H}_d$ which, when [exponentiated](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matrix_exponential), leads to a [d-dimensional cyclic permutation transformation matrix](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1070035/157257).

---

I have solutions for **d=2**:

$$
    \hat{U}_2 =\left( \begin{matrix}
    0 & 1 \\
    1 & 0 \\
   \end{matrix} \right)=-i \exp\left(i\hat{H_2}\right) \to \\
    \hat{H}_2 =\left( \begin{matrix}
    0 & 1 \\
    1 & 0 \\
   \end{matrix} \right)
$$

---

**d=3:**

$$
    \hat{U}_3 =\left( \begin{matrix}
    0 & 1 & 0 \\
    0 & 0 & 1 \\
    1 & 0 & 0\\
   \end{matrix} \right)=-i \exp\left(i\hat{H_3}\right) \to \\
    \hat{H}_3 =\frac{\pi}{3}\left( \begin{matrix}
    -\frac{1}{2} & \left(-\frac{1}{\sqrt{3}} + i \right) & \left(\frac{1}{\sqrt{3}} + i \right) \\
    \left(\frac{1}{\sqrt{3}} + i \right) & -\frac{1}{2} & \left(-\frac{1}{\sqrt{3}} + i \right)\\
    \left(\frac{1}{\sqrt{3}} + i \right) & \left(-\frac{1}{\sqrt{3}} + i \right) & -\frac{1}{2}
   \end{matrix}  \right)
$$

---

**d=4:**

$$
    \hat{U}_4 =\left( \begin{matrix}
    0 & 1 & 0 & 0 \\
    0 & 0 & 1 & 0 \\
    0 & 0 & 0 & 1 \\
    1 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
   \end{matrix} \right)=-i \exp\left(i\hat{H_4}\right) \to \\
    \hat{H}_4 =\frac{\pi}{4}\left( \begin{matrix}
    i & (1+i) & -i & (-1+i) \\
     (-1+i) & i & (1+i) & -i\\
     -i & (-1+i) & i & (1+i)\\
    (1+i) & -i & (-1+i) & i \\
   \end{matrix}  \right)
$$

---

Unfortunately, I am missing a general form of $H_d$ for $d>4$, so my question is:

> **Question:** How does $\hat{H}_d$ look when I want that $\hat{U}_d=-i \exp\left(i \hat{H}_d \right)$ is a d-dimensional cyclic permutation transformation?

Comment: Since the matrix is circulant you can diagonalize it. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Circulant_matrix maybe that helps

Comment: Because of different branches of the logarithm function, the answer is not unique.  For example there is a solution for $\hat H_3$ with zeros on the diagonal.

Comment: Thanks, both of your comments are very useful, and i already see some progress because of them. Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

The article below presents the general form:

https://arxiv.org/abs/2001.11909